# I dont get values when i request HTML using beatifulsoup (python)

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am currently building my own "stock" tracker.

I have a hard time extracting the right values from websites when scraping.
On the online html-code h2 has a value, but when i request it, h2 doesn't bring along this value.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = requests.get("https://npinvestor.dk/kursinfo/vis-aktie/172.1.MAERSK-B:2").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")

stock = soup.find('h2', class_="change-pct text-right change-flash change-color")
print(stock)

stock_2 = soup.find('h2', class_="change-pct text-right change-flash change-color").text
print(stock_2)
```

my output:

```
<h2 class="change-pct text-right change-flash change-color" style="width: 120px; float: left;"> </h2>
```

Comment: output: 
<h2 class="change-pct text-right change-flash change-color" style="width: 120px; float: left;"> </h2>

Answer (score 0):

The data you're trying to get is dynamically added by `JS`, which means `bs4` won't see those.

However, you can try the API endpoint.

For example:

```
import requests

API_endpoint = "https://npinvestor.dk/javascript/ajax/stock_details.php?symbol=172.1.MAERSK-B&provider=2&frequency=60"
data = requests.get(API_endpoint).json()

print(data["symbol"], data["close_price"])
```

Output:

```
172.1.MAERSK/B 13660
```

The entire response looks like this:

```
{
    "company_name": "A.P. M\u00f8ller - M\u00e6rsk B",
    "isin": "DK0010244508",
    "symbol": "172.1.MAERSK/B",
    "tstamp": "2021-01-26 12:02:36",
    "last": "13215",
    "lowest": "13170",
    "highest": "13600",
    "close_price": "13660",
    "volume": "23053",
    "bid": "13205",
    "ask": "13210",
    "change_pct": "-3.257686676427529",
    "change_pt": "-445",
    "data_provider": "2",
    "provider_name": "OMX",
    "delay_type": "1"
}
```